# Using echo "" to create a new empty file isn't creating an empty file

Tags: files, echo

I needed to create an empty file. So I used this:

```bsh
echo "" > file
```

Then when I am performing a check in my program (if the file is empty) like this,

```javascript
if(file.content == '')
   do something
```

The if block never executes.

When I open the file using `nano file`, there's nothing in the file. I even tried doing this `print(file.content)`, the output is still empty.

What's causing this error? And what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
echo ""
```

outputs a newline, so your file isn’t empty, it contains a newline. `ls -l` will show you that its size is one byte.

To create an empty file, use a command with no output:

```
: > file
```

Comment: +1.  there's also `touch file` to create an empty file.

Comment: @cas yes, with the caveat that it shouldn’t exist beforehand ;-).

Comment: for that, there's `truncate -s 0 file` :-)

Comment: which is to say you could use `printf "" > file` instead :)

Answer (score -1):

```
~ > echo "" > t                                                                                                                       bill at LAPTOP-0GVE7LSM
~ > cat t                                                                                                                             bill at LAPTOP-0GVE7LSM

~ > vim tt                                                                                                                            bill at LAPTOP-0GVE7LSM
~ > cat tt                                                                                                                            bill at LAPTOP-0GVE7LSM
~ >                                                                                                                                   bill at LAPTOP-0GVE7LSM
```

As is shown below, cat got the content in the file.

In file tt, I really input nothing, the it out put nothing.

However, in file t, you cat a new line, which is '\n'.

Comment: Look at the file with `od -bc file`.

Comment: @waltinator It outputted 0000000. What does this mean?